# Contar el número de clientes que hacen más de 1 compra en 1 mes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Quiero encontrar el número de clientes que hacen compras "repetitivas", esto significa, aquellos clientes que en 1 mes han realizado más de 1 compra para el año 2017.

Tengo el siguiente dataset:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento he filtrado los datos para el año 2017:

```
select * from transactions
where data_move >= '01/01/17'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, no consigo saber como contar las compras por mes para cada cliente y evaluarlo si estas han sido en un periodo inferior a 1 mes. Cómo podría hacerlo?

Para el caso en concreto, debería obtener que el cliente 25 ha realizado 2 compras en 1 periodo inferior a 1 mes así como también el cliente 43

Comment: esto yo no lo haría en una query en verda, es algo mas complejo, ya que lo que tu quieres es: buscar todas las compras, luego agruparlas por usuario y evaluar si este usuario hace mas de una compra en menos de 30 días, si es así, agrupas estos periodos, ej: usuario 1 tiene su primera compra el 2017/01/01, a partir de esta fecha le sumo 30 días, comprobar si hay mas de una compra en estos 30 días y si las hay crear y guardar este periodo. Ahora la pregunta es, ¿se sigue con la fecha 2 o paso a una fecha posterior a este periodo?, esto es muy complejo yo simplemente no lo veo en una query

Comment: @LPZadkiel yo no consigo ver la solución. Cualquier ayuda es buena!

Comment: El motor es Oracle @Sal . Ahora quito la etiqueta.

Answer (score 1):

Quizas te funcione, no tengo Oracle a la mano, sin embargo si tengo un escenario parecido al tuyo en PostgreSQL, ¿Es esto lo que estas buscando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es así, este seria código: (de pronto lo puedes traducir a PL/SQL)

```
SELECT aa.idcliente , aa.fecha_venta , aa.mes  FROM  (SELECT d1.idcliente, d1.fecha_venta, TRUNC((DATE_PART('day', d1.fecha_venta - (SELECT MIN(d2.fecha_venta) FROM ventas d2 WHERE d2.idcliente = d1.idcliente )))/30) +1 mes FROM  ventas d1 WHERE d1.idcliente = 3547 ORDER BY d1.idcliente, d1.fecha_venta) aa
```

Supuestos: intervalo es de 30 días a partir de la fecha de la primera transacción, el resto sería la agrupación eso lo dejo en tus manos.

Saludos, larga vida y prosperidad

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Intrepid DvD no consigo entender como hacer un join sin una clausula join... me cuesta traducir tu código a Oracle. Podrías explicar paso por paso la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Esto te devolvería los clientes que en cada mes tuvieron más de 1 compra y la cantidad de compras en ese mes:

```
select Customer_Id 'Cliente', Month(data_move) 'Mes',Count(*) 'Cantidad de Compras' from transactions
where data_move >= '01/01/17'
group by Customer_Id, MONTH(data_move)
having Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Quizás no me he explicado bien, podría ser que un cliente hubiera realizado la compra el 2/05/2017 y otra compra el 1/06/2017. Por lo tanto, existiria una ventana de 1 mes en la que se han realizado dos compras. En el caso que tu me comentas creo que solo estamos agrupando compras por mes y cliente @Guido Lorenzatti